# Flume: Avro event deserializer To Elastic Search

Tags: java, avro, flume-ng

I want to take a record created by the AVRO deserializer and send it to ElasticSearch. I realize I have to write custom code to do this.

Using the LITERAL option, I have the JSON schema that is the first step in using the GenericRecord. However, looking throughout the AVRO Java API, I see no way of using GenericRecord for one record. All examples use DataFileReader.

In short, I can't get the fields from the Flume event.

Has anyone done this before?
TIA.

Comment: I figured it out and posted the solution. Thank you very much. This was my first post but I read the site a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I did the following:

```
// Get the schema
String strSchema = event.getHeader("flume.avro.schema.literal");
// Get the body
byte[] body = event.getBody();

// Create the avro schema
Schema schema = Schema.Parser.parse(strSchema);

// Get the decoder to use to get the "record" from the event stream in object form
BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.binaryDecoder(body, null); 

// Get the datum reader
GenericDatumReader reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);

// Get the Avro record in object form
GenericRecord record = reader.read(null, decoder);

// Now you can iterate over the fields
for (Schema.Field field : schema.getFields()) {
   Object value = record.get(field.name());

   // Code to add field to JSON to send to ElasticSearch not listed
   // ...

} // for (Schema.Field field : schema.getFields()) {
```

This works well.